# Javascript multiple highlight text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, highlight

I am trying to highlight text using multiple color. But text are not highlighting. Below example given

```
<span class='classOne'>Hello there <span class='classTwo'>highlight not</span> working.</span>
```

For Single color it works fine not for multiple. Below given my source code got from google search.

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function (pat) {
    function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
        var skip = 0;
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
            if (pos >= 0) {
                var spannode = document.createElement('span');
                spannode.className = 'highlight';
                var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
                var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
                var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
                skip = 1;
            }
        } else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
            }
        }
        return skip;
    }
    return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function () {
        innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
    }) : this;
};

jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function () {
    return this.find("span.highlight").each(function () {
        this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;
        with(this.parentNode) {
            replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
            normalize();
        }
    }).end();
};
```

Comment: Could you please add running code snippet or a jsfiddle?

Comment: please check the demo from here .. http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Well it worked when I did it. Check this out.

```js
$.fn.highlight = function (pat) {
    function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
        var skip = 0;
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
            if (pos >= 0) {
                var spannode = document.createElement('span');
                spannode.className = 'highlight';
                var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
                var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
                var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
                skip = 1;
            }
        } else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
            }
        }
        return skip;
    }
    return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function () {
        innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
    }) : this;
};

$.fn.removeHighlight = function () {
    return this.find("span.highlight").each(function () {
        this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;
        with(this.parentNode) {
            replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
            normalize();
        }
    }).end();
};

$('.classOne').highlight('Hello');
$('.classTwo').highlight('highlight');
```

```css
.classOne .highlight {
    background-color: #FF0;
}

.classTwo .highlight {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='classOne'>Hello there <span class='classTwo'>highlight</span> working now.</span>
```

For multicolor you'll have to write different CSS classes or may be update the logic which adds `highlight` class to add multiple classes in order to support multicolor.